# R set initial value

Tags: r, dataframe

There is a data.frame:

```
a<-c(2,8,6,5,8)
b<-c(1,6,7,3,2)
df<-data.frame(a,b)
```

[image]

It has to be created a column d, which is calculated: 
First element of the column d[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1xbN.png) = a[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1xbN.png) + b[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1xbN.png)
The other elements of the column d[2:5] = ifelse ( shift(d) > a, a, shift(d)+a )
As a result, I want to receive the following data frame:

[image]

How can I set the initial value (first element) of the row d?
Thank You!

Comment: `shift` is not a base R function. Where does `shift` come from?

Comment: First element of the column: d(1])= a(1) + b(1).

Comment: Create the column as `NA`, `df$d = NA`, then set your first values `df$d[1] = df$a[1] + df$b[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have correctly understood your question:

```
df$d <- NA
df$d[1] <- df$a[1] + df$b[1]
for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
  df$d[i] = ifelse(df$d[i-1] > df$a[i], df$a[i], df$d[i-1]+df$a[i])
}

df

  a b  d
1 2 1  3
2 8 6 11
3 6 7  6
4 5 3  5
5 8 2 13
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank You very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.